# Terminology on Ubuntu stopped working

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon, terminology

Terminology (terminal emulator) was working fine till this morning (11th march 2015). So I suppose it should be an upgrade issue.

Now I get this error

```
ERR<8250>:eio lib/eio/eio_monitor.c:339 eio_monitor_stringshared_add() monitored path '/home/moo/.elementary/config/standard' not found.
ERR<8098>:eo lib/eo/eo_ptr_indirection.c:22 _eo_pointer_error() Class (0x7ffdace841c8) is an invalid ref.
ERR<8098>:eo lib/eo/eo.c:530 _eo_api_op_id_get() Unable to resolve op for api func 0x7f08b7197540
CRI<8098>:terminology main.c:901 elm_main() Could not create window.
ERR<8098>: elm_prefs.c:1857 _elm_prefs_shutdown() Init count not greater than 0 in shutdown.
ERR<8098>:eo lib/eo/eo_ptr_indirection.c:22 _eo_pointer_error() Class (0x7f08baeedc98) is an invalid ref.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the package then reinstall it. That might fix any problems you might have.

It's just a terminal emulator so not much to lose

Comment: tried it and it did not work, I have waited for a while and with the next version seems everything is in place. I should have reported the issue to their website.
thanks for the help anyways